# Finding the Hopf Algebra Coproduct coming from an Affine Group Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I was wondering if anyone could help with how to, strictly from Yoneda's Lemma, obtain the coproduct map on the Hopf Algebra for an Affine Group Scheme. Particularly for something like $\text{SL}_2$

So if $G=\text{SL}_2$, let  $m:G \times G \to G$ be the multiplication map. Yoneda'e lemma tells us that this induces a map $\Delta:A \to A \otimes A$ and there is a specific construction:

$m: G\times G(A \otimes A) \to G(A \otimes A)$ which (since $G$ is representable is just a map $\text{Hom}(A \otimes A, A \otimes A) \to \text{Hom}(A, A \otimes A)$ and element-wise $id$ gets sent to $\Delta$.

This is hypothetically how you should "find" $\Delta$. In the case of $\text{SL}_2$ I guess the part I am having trouble with is finding the corresponding element in $G\times G(A \otimes A)$ that goes with $id$. That way I can just do the multiplication map and see what the entries are to get the $\Delta$ map.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's wrong with just using the identification of affine schemes over $k$ with the opposite of $k$-algebras? Namely, you know that $\text{SL}_2$ as an (affine) scheme is just $\text{Spec}A$ where $A=k[\{x_{i,j}\}]/(\det \{x_{i,j}\}-1)$, and you know explicitly what $m$ is. Then, by dualizing you get a map $m^\ast:A\to A\otimes A$, this $m^\ast$ is your $\Delta$. Why go strictly through Yoneda? Just for funsies? This is, in essence, with Matt said below.

Comment: The functor definition is nice, and compact, but knowing by the equivalence of categories that group objects in $\mathbf{ASch}/k$ (affine schemes) correspond to co-group objects in $k-\mathbf{Alg}$ (which are just Hopf algebras) seems supremely nice. The above method of producing the comultiplication map highlights this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about we do $\mathbb G_m$ (or $GL_1$, if you prefer to denote it that way),so
there is less notation.

The ring $A$ is equal to $k[x,x^{-1}]$, so $A \otimes A $ equals $k[x,x^{-1},y,y^{-1}]$ (thinking of $x$ as $x\otimes 1$ and $y$ as $1 \otimes x$, if you see what I mean).

Now the identity map from $A$ to $A$ corresponds to the element $x \in \mathbb G_m(A)$ (since the identification of $\mathrm{Hom}(A,A')$ with $\mathbb G_m$ is given by sending a homomorphism $\varphi$ to the element $\varphi(x) \in A'$), and so the identity map of $A\otimes A$ corresponds to the pair $(x,y)
\in (\mathbb G_m\times \mathbb  G_m)(A\otimes A) = \mathbb G_m(A\otimes A) \times 
\mathbb G_m(A\otimes A)$.

When we multiply these two elements, we get $xy \in \mathbb G_m(A\otimes A)$,
and thus $\Delta$ is given by $x \mapsto xy$.

In general, $\Delta$ just expresses the formula for $m$ in coordinates.
So for $SL_2$, if we label the generators of $A$ as $a,b,c,d$ (with 
the relation $ad - bc = 1$), and label the generators of $A \otimes A$
as $a,b,c,d,a',b',c',d'$ (rather than $a\otimes 1$, etc., $1\otimes a$, etc.),
then $\Delta$ will have the formula
$$a \mapsto a a' + bc', \text{ etc.},$$
just coming from the formula
$$\pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}\cdot \pmatrix{a' & b'\\ c' & d'} = 
\pmatrix{a a' + b c' & a b' + b d' \\ c a' + d c' & c b' + d d'}.$$

If you want to derive this via your Yoneda strategy, it will work exactly
as with the $\mathbb G_m$ example (just with more notation, because
there are more generators for $A$).

Comment: So it seems to me from what you wrote that the identity element in $G\times G(A \otimes A)$ is $(\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \otimes 1 & x_2 \otimes 1 \\ x_3 \otimes 1 & x_4 \otimes 1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 \otimes x_1 & 1 \otimes x_2 \\ 1 \otimes x_3 & 1 \otimes x_4 \end{pmatrix} )$?

Comment: @SeanBallentine: Dear Sean, Yes, that's right.  Regards,